# Why a substraction has a different result if computed from a dataframe? in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subtraction

I have been checking my data and I realized that a substraction was wrong, and I computed it mannually and I get the correct result.

My question is why when I computed the substraction from the data.frame it gives a number .5 and when I computed it with just the numbers it gives me the correct results.

I tried to reproduce the problem in other computer and here is a toy example of this problem

```
a <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = 4))
a[1,] <- c(101292229, 101298224, 101190466, 101195700)
colnames(a) <- c("start_I","end_I","start_II","end_II")

a$MI <- (a$start_I + a$end_I)/2
a$MII <- (a$start_II + a$end_II)/2

a

    start_I     end_I  start_II    end_II        MI       MII
1 101292229 101298224 101190466 101195700 101295226 101193083

a$MII-a$MI

[1] -102143.5

101193083-101295226

[1] -102143
```

Comment: Try this: `sprintf("%f", a)`. When you print `a`, `MI` is being rounded, so your manual calculation is using incorrect numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As Lyngbakr pointed out, `a$MI` is actually `101295226.5`, but only appears to be `101295226`  due to the default printing settings cutting off the decimal place.

If you override those settings with `format()`, you'll see the extra `.5` appear:

```
format(a, digits = 10)
    start_I     end_I  start_II    end_II          MI       MII
1 101292229 101298224 101190466 101195700 101295226.5 101193083
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`as.integer(a$MII-a$MI)`

to get the results that you are expecting